# Center of mass for pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to find a center of mass for N-dimensional space in Python.I have a dataframe with K columns (some contain text and some contain numbers)

{X1...Xk}
...
{Z1..Zk}

k > 10000

I need to calculate center of mass for all numerical values in the dataframe.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Is each row a material point? Are masses of points same? In this case just remove string columns and calculate mean of points. Probably, there are libs with such function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center of mass is simply the mean of the values on each dimension, and you just want to calculate it on non-object columns, so:

```
df.ix[:,df.dtypes != 'O'].mean()
```

**EDIT:** although the OP only mentioned "text" and "numbers", the following alternative is indeed more general (thanks MaxU):

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).mean()
```

Comment: I think a bit robuster version would be `df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).mean()`, because there are also `datetime`, `category`, etc. dtypes...